# En este codigo quiero cambiar de color el texto al dar click pero no me sale... no se donde esta el error

Tags: javascript, html

En este codigo quiero cambiar de color el texto al dar click pero no me sale... no se donde esta el error

```js
        function changeColor(id) {
            el = document.getElementById('p');
            if (el.style.color == rgb(0,255,0)) {
                el.style.color = rgb(255,0,0);
            }else{
                el.style.color = rgb(0,255,0);
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cambiando de color</h1>
    <div style="color:rgb(0,255,0)" id='p'>
    Este es el texto a cambiar
</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('p')">Cambiar</button>
</body>
</html>
introducir el código aquí
```

En este codigo quiero cambiar de color el texto al dar click pero no me sale... no se donde esta el error

Comment: Hay que aprender a depurar el código... Pista: hacé `console.log` del color actual de tu elemento, antes del `if`. Además, la función `rgb` es de CSS, no de JS. Al ejecutar el snippet, explícitamente te dice `rgb is not defined`.

Comment: todos los rgb que tienes en tu js tienen que estar entre comillas => `"rgb(0,255,0)"`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que obtienes al extraer el estilo del elemento es un **String** por lo que tanto al compararlo, como al asignarle valor, debes de hacerlo a través de un **String**.

Hay que considerar también que el formato en el que te es devuelto el color mete un espacio después de cada coma, por lo que en tu comparación se tiene que ver contemplado.

```js
function changeColor() {
  const el = document.getElementById('p')
  
  if (el.style.color === 'rgb(0, 255, 0)') {
    el.style.color = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
  }
  else{
    el.style.color = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cambiando de color</h1>
    <div style="color:rgb(0,255,0)" id='p'>
    Este es el texto a cambiar
</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('p')">Cambiar</button>
</body>
</html>
introducir el código aquí
```